# Random generator always amounting to 0 (Java)

Tags: java

I am working through Head First Java, and my Random generator is amounting to 0. Here are my classes:
This is my class with the main method.

```
public class GameLauncher {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GuessGame game = new GuessGame();
    game.startGame();
}
}
```

This is my player object class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Player {
    int number = 0; //Where the guess goes

    public void guess() {
        //random1 is in GuessGame
        Random random2 = new Random();
        int number = random2.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("I'm guessing " + number);
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the class where most of  the code is happening.

```
  import java.util.Random;

public class GuessGame {
    //Guessgame has three instance variables for the three Player objects
    Player p1;
    Player p2;
    Player p3;

    public void startGame() {
        //Create three Player objects and assign them to the three Player instance variables
        p1 = new Player();
        p2 = new Player();
        p3 = new Player();
        //Declare three variables to hold the three guesses the players make
        int guessp1 = 0;
        int guessp2 = 0;
        int guessp3 = 0;
        //Declare three variables to hold a true or false based on the player's answer
        boolean p1isRight = false;
        boolean p2isRight = false;
        boolean p3isRight = false;
        //Make a "target" number that the players have to guess
        Random random = new Random();
        //Generate a number between 0 and 9
        int targetNumber = random.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 0 and 9...");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Number to guess is " + targetNumber);
            //Call each player's guess() method
            p1.guess();
            p2.guess();
            p3.guess();
            /*
            Get each player's guess (the result of their guess() method
            running) by accessing the number variable of each player
            */
            guessp1 = p1.number;
            guessp2 = p2.number;
            guessp3 = p3.number;
            System.out.println("Player one guessed " + guessp1);
            System.out.println("Player two guessed " + guessp2);
            System.out.println("Player three guessed " + guessp3);
            /*
            Check each player's guess to see if it matches the target number. If a player is right, then set that player's variable to be true (remember, we set it false by default)
             */
            if (guessp1 == targetNumber) {
                p1isRight = true;
            }
            if (guessp2 == targetNumber) {
                p2isRight = true;
            }
            if (guessp3 == targetNumber) {
                p3isRight = true;
            }
            //If player one OR player two OR player three is right... (the || operator means OR)
            if (p1isRight || p2isRight || p3isRight) {
                System.out.println("We have a winner!");
                System.out.println("Player one got it right? " + p1isRight);
                System.out.println("Player two got it right? " + p2isRight);
                System.out.println("Player three got it right? " + p3isRight);
                System.out.println("Game is over.");
                break; //Game over, so break out of the loop
            }
            else {
                //We must keep going because nobody got it right!

                System.out.println("Players will have to try again.");
            } //end if/else
        } //end loop
    } //end method
    } //end class
```

I am new to these forums, so if I did something wrong please let me know :)
Does anyone know why this isn't working?
Thanks,
Lyfe

Comment: how you are running this game. is there a main method or calling this from another program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing random number in local variable and you think you set it in [instance variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

at line

```
int number = random2.nextInt(10);
```

change it to

```
this.number = random2.nextInt(10);
```

that atleast solves stated problem.

**Also See**

- [Java Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Also See [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: It says I have to wait 5 minutes, I'll accept it then.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out for a while now why this fixes the problem, could you please explain to me in a bit more detail?

Comment: @Lyfe see the link in the answer. specifically around local variables and instance variables